# Is there a controller for a 404 page (Play! Framework)

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am working with Play! Framework 1.2.4 and have no problems creating static 404 pages.  However, I would like to make the 404 page a little more dynamic.

Is there a "controller" for a 404 page?  If not, where do I do all my logic that would traditionally go in the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no controller for a 404 page. Play try to find a route and if this is not possible throw a NotFound Result that shows the 404 page.

You may create a catch all controller that do this job so this controller will handle the 404 case instead of Play itself.

```
 *       /.*     NotFoundRouter.notFoundPage
```

Answer (score 3):

As Nasir said, you can respond with the NotFound Action in any controller to return a 404 response.  We typically respond with the Ok Action for the proper 200 Http response code.  An example (play 2 -- not sure if it works for play 1):

```
object BadgeEvidence extends Controller {
  def index(badgeName: String, earner: String) = Action {
    val badgeResponse = BadgeDao.getBadgeDetail(badgeName)
    val evidence = BadgeDao.getBadgeEvidence(badgeName, earner)
    if (evidence.length == 0) {
        NotFound(earner + " is not valid or has not earned " + badgeName);
    } else {
      badgeResponse match {
        case badgeDetail: BadgeRow => Ok(views.html.badgeEvidence(earner, badgeDetail, evidence))
        case errorMessage: String => Ok(views.html.showError(errorMessage))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GlobalSettings.onHandlerNotFound() to handle the requests which will get 404 response.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/GlobalSettings.html

Comment: your answer is appropriate for Play2, but the OP specified he was using Play 1.x

Answer (score 0):

You can do some coding inside `app/views/errors/404.html` template file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not certain how dynamic you intend it to be. Deep down, [NotFound](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/results/NotFound.java) class is responsible for loading the 404.html. Perhaps, it can be useful to you.