# Is there a way to use EntityManager in play! framework 1.2.x 404 page?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

we are providing custom 404.html page (in app/views/errors) for play! 1.2.5

During serving 404 we would like to connect to DB, but when doing so we get:

```
play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized. 
JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated
with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.
at play.db.jpa.JPA.get(JPA.java:22)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:51)
at play.db.jpa.JPQL.em(JPQL.java:18)
at play.db.jpa.JPQL.find(JPQL.java:46)
...
at controllers.Security.check(Security.java:146)
at play.utils.Java.invokeStaticOrParent(Java.java:162)
at play.utils.Java.invokeChildOrStatic(Java.java:184)
at controllers.Secure$Security.invoke(Secure.java:203)
...
at play.server.PlayHandler.serve404(PlayHandler.java:681)
```

Should I go for a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242994/1444089 - so defining my own controller handler instead of just a template?

Maybe there is some configuration option for that, but couldn't find one.

And last but not least - why is this happening, is there a reason why 404 goes in some other request lifecycle than a typical play request?

Answer (score 1):

You may use JPAPlugin methods startTx and closeTx inside a try/finally

```
JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
try {
    // your code
} finally {
    JPAPlugin.closeTx();
}
```